# What is the best place to receive socket messages ? [React, Redux, Web sockets]

Tags: reactjs, sockets, redux, websocket, socket.io

I think opening a connection is a good place for redux middleware (in the actions) however I am not sure where I should handle receiving data like `socket.on()`. The users in my app are queued. I want to get updates on when they move up in the queue with sockets rather than polling. Should I do it in the ComponentDidMount to update my state when I receive an update?

Comment: Socket listeners must be attached in componentDidMount function as they only need to be initialised once

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll keep that in mind. If I open a connection in my redux middleware (using thunk), will that keep the connection across the whole project and I can listen to socket events anywhere? Or do I have to open socket connections in componentDidMount in my root App component?

Comment: You can create an instance once, either in your root component or a middleware and share it across the app